# How to setContentView in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

Now I've got this fragment which i want to use setContentView with but so far i cant find how. You can see my case in the code below, im not trying to inflate a layout, im trying to use it with the view called SampleView. So how can I do that?

```
public class largeImageScroller extends SherlockFragment {
 
// Physical display width and height.
private static int displayWidth = 0;
private static int displayHeight = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved) {

        getActivity();
        // displayWidth and displayHeight will change depending on screen
        // orientation. To get these dynamically, we should hook onSizeChanged().
        // This simple example uses only landscape mode, so it's ok to get them
        // once on startup and use those values throughout.
        
        Display display = ((WindowManager)
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        displayWidth = display.getWidth();             
        displayHeight = display.getHeight();    

        // SampleView constructor must be constructed last as it needs the
        // displayWidth and displayHeight we just got.
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
}

private static class SampleView extends View {
        private static Bitmap bmLargeImage; //bitmap large enough to be scrolled
        private static Rect displayRect = null; //rect we display to
        private Rect scrollRect = null; //rect we scroll over our bitmap with
        private int scrollRectX = 0; //current left location of scroll rect
        private int scrollRectY = 0; //current top location of scroll rect
        private float scrollByX = 0; //x amount to scroll by
        private float scrollByY = 0; //y amount to scroll by
        private float startX = 0; //track x from one ACTION_MOVE to the next
        private float startY = 0; //track y from one ACTION_MOVE to the next

        public SampleView(Context context) {
                super(context);

                // Destination rect for our main canvas draw. It never changes.
                displayRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
                // Scroll rect: this will be used to 'scroll around' over the
                // bitmap in memory. Initialize as above.
                scrollRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);

                // Load a large bitmap into an offscreen area of memory.
                bmLargeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ground_floor_b);
        }
       
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                // Remember our initial down event location.
                                startX = event.getRawX();
                                startY = event.getRawY();
                                break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                float x = event.getRawX();
                                float y = event.getRawY();
                                // Calculate move update. This will happen many times
                                // during the course of a single movement gesture.
                                scrollByX = x - startX; //move update x increment
                                scrollByY = y - startY; //move update y increment
                                startX = x; //reset initial values to latest
                                startY = y;
                                invalidate(); //force a redraw
                                break;
                }
                return true; //done with this event so consume it
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                // Our move updates are calculated in ACTION_MOVE in the opposite direction
                // from how we want to move the scroll rect. Think of this as dragging to
                // the left being the same as sliding the scroll rect to the right.
                int newScrollRectX = scrollRectX - (int)scrollByX;
                int newScrollRectY = scrollRectY - (int)scrollByY;

                // Don't scroll off the left or right edges of the bitmap.
                if (newScrollRectX < 0)
                        newScrollRectX = 0;
                else if (newScrollRectX > (bmLargeImage.getWidth() - displayWidth))
                        newScrollRectX = (bmLargeImage.getWidth() - displayWidth);

                // Don't scroll off the top or bottom edges of the bitmap.
                if (newScrollRectY < 0)
                        newScrollRectY = 0;
                else if (newScrollRectY > (bmLargeImage.getHeight() - displayHeight))
                        newScrollRectY = (bmLargeImage.getHeight() - displayHeight);

                // We have our updated scroll rect coordinates, set them and draw.
                scrollRect.set(newScrollRectX, newScrollRectY,
                        newScrollRectX + displayWidth, newScrollRectY + displayHeight);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmLargeImage, scrollRect, displayRect, paint);

                // Reset current scroll coordinates to reflect the latest updates,
                // so we can repeat this update process.
                scrollRectX = newScrollRectX;
                scrollRectY = newScrollRectY;
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You dont call `setContentView` in fragments, in fact you need to return a `View` from `onCreateView`.

Try replacing:

```
setContentView(new SampleView(this));
```

With this:

```
return new SampleView(this);
```

Comment: For me, I had to do like `return new SampleView(getActivity());`

Answer (score 33):

Return the view instance you want to use:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_tab, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Also it's not safe to call `getActivity()` from `onCreateView()`.
Make sure you call it in or after `onActivityCreated()`, as at this point your `Fragment` is fully associated with the `Activity`. Check `Fragment`'s lifecycle.

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: The documentation does indeed say to watch out and wait for the fragment to be attached. However, I don't see it mentioning this means waiting for the activity to be created (i.e. its `onCreate` having retuned). The `onAttach` should IMHO be fine (though I am rather new to Android development) and it's called before `onCreateView`. Am I missing something?

Comment: On the other hand, some (official) examples suggest that you are right. I guess it's better that way.

Answer (score 3):

As explained already, you need to return the view in case of fragments.
But still if you want to use it just like `setContentView()`, you can do so in following way.

1.Put this code snippet wherever you had to put `setContentView()`

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
```

2.Now if you want to access something from xml file, you can do so by using

```
chart = v.findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

3. And in the end of `OnCreateView()` you will have to put

```
return v;
```

Full example :

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

    chart = v.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    return v;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In activities we need to set the view using `setContentView(R.layout.main)`

Where as in fragments we need to override `onCreateView()` to set the desired view.