# setContentView cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I have an activity and a fragment. The fragment's java file is currently empty.
Below is the code for my activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class CrimeActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

}
}
```

When I try running my app, the error message is

```
Error:(15, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
```

is I have tried searching for an answer but to no avail. I have cleaned my project and restarted Android Studio thrice. There are also no errors in the XML files.

Comment: CrimeActivity extends Fragment, not Activity! And Fragment does not have method setContentView()

Comment: use onCreateView instead to view layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-

```
public class CrimeActivity extends Activity{
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

} 
}
```

---

2-

```
public class CrimeActivity extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_crime, container, false);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are extending Fragment not Activity therefore you do not call setContentView as it does not exist for Fragment.

Please see previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108370/how-to-setcontentview-in-a-fragment) for further information.

If you want to continue using fragments look at overriding the onCreateView() method.

Answer (score 0):

Select:

File---->invalidate caches/restart ---->invalidate and restart

By this android studio restarts and that error is gone..

Hope it helps